# How to Show Spinner in Number on Every HTTP Request and HTTP Response in angular 6 with typescript

Tags: typescript, angular6, spinner, percentage

I am Implementing Show Spinner on Every **`HTTP Request`** and **`HTTP Response`** on every **API** Call now i want to show spinner in number that means how much response is done and i want to calculate that response in number so how to **implement** that i don't know and here i my code.

This is my **loader.interceptor.ts**

```
// loader.interceptors.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoaderService } from './loader.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private requests: HttpRequest<any>[] = [];

    constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

    removeRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
        const i = this.requests.indexOf(req);
        if (i >= 0) {
            this.requests.splice(i, 1);
        }
        this.loaderService.isLoading.next(this.requests.length > 0);
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.requests.push(req);
        console.log("No of requests--->" + this.requests.length);
        this.loaderService.isLoading.next(true);
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            const subscription = next.handle(req)
                .subscribe(
                    event => {
                        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                            this.removeRequest(req);
                            observer.next(event);
                        }
                    },
                    err => {
                        alert('error returned');
                        this.removeRequest(req);
                        observer.error(err);
                    },
                    () => {
                        this.removeRequest(req);
                        observer.complete();
                    });
            // remove request from queue when cancelled
            return () => {
                this.removeRequest(req);
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            };
        });
    }
}
```

This is my **loader.component.html**

```
<!-- loader.component.html -->
<div class="progress-loader" [hidden]="!loading">
    Loading...
</div>
```

This is my **loader.component.ts**

```
//loader.interceptor.ts
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
      import { LoaderService } from '../loader.service';

      @Component({
        selector: 'app-loading',
        templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./loading.component.css']
      })
      export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {

        loading: boolean;
        constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {
          this.loaderService.isLoading.subscribe((v) => {
            console.log(v);
            this.loading = v;
          });
        }
        ngOnInit() {
        }
      }
```

This is my **app.component.html**

```
<app-loading></app-loading>
```

Here is my Spinner Image

[image]

My **Expectation** is Show Spinner with percentage that means how much response is load when API is Request.

Eg: **out of 100% the 40% load** is done from response
i search many resource from internet and stackoverflow but not getting the proper implementation so can u give some solution on this topic

Comment: There is no way for a client to know in advance how much time the server will take to process a request, and how much time the network is going to take to send the request and receive the response.

Comment: ok...Sir so there is no way to achieve this things, but any other way or something new we can achieve with spinner

Comment: Most such spinners are either completely interterminate, or give a fake progression bar, for example by going to 50% after 500ms, then 75% after 1000ms, then 87.5% after 1500ms, etc.

Comment: +1 ohh..ok..i'll not use fake spinner i'll use just simple spinner but @JB Nizet Thankyou for ur reply ....thanks a lot ☻